Erro de execução do script python no agendador de tarefas do windowns, WIN32
Toda vez que tento executar meu script python no agendador de tarefa do windows ele aparece esse erro:
Imagem do erro
Segue o script:
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Font, PatternFill, Alignment, Border, Side
import win32com.client as win32

def enviar_relatorio():
    # Configurações do caminho do arquivo
    caminho_arquivo = r'\\hughes.corp\company\TEMPORARIO\qlik\SharedFiles\IN\Financeiro\ONG-RelatNegociacao-horario.csv'
    caminho_relatorio_filtrado = r'\\hughes.corp\company\Fin\CONSUMER - CONTAS A RECEBER\CRÉDITO E COBRANÇA CONSUMER\AUTOMAÇÃO PLANILHAS\ONG-RelatNegociacao-hora-a-hora.xlsx'

    # Abre o Excel
    excel = win32.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    excel.Visible = True  # Isso garante que o Excel não seja aberto em segundo plano

    # Abre o arquivo Excel
    workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(caminho_arquivo)

    # Atualiza a planilha
    workbook.RefreshAll()

    # Aguarda um momento para que a planilha seja atualizada (ajuste conforme necessário)
    import time
    time.sleep(200)

    # Fecha o arquivo
    workbook.Close(SaveChanges=True)

    # Fecha o Excel
    excel.Quit()

    # Data do dia vigente
    data_vigente = datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

    # Lê o arquivo CSV, tratando o BOM
    df = pd.read_csv(caminho_arquivo, sep=';', encoding='utf-8-sig')

    # Converte as colunas de data para datetime
    df['Data Negociação'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Data Negociação'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', errors='coerce')
    df['Data Efetivação'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Data Efetivação'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', errors='coerce')
    df['Data Cancelamento'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Data Cancelamento'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', errors='coerce')

    # Formata a coluna 'Valor Negociado Final' para número
    df['Valor Negociado Final'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Valor Negociado Final'].str.replace(',', '.'), errors='coerce')

    # Filtra pelos dados do dia vigente
    df_filtrado = df[df['Data Negociação'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') == data_vigente].copy()

    # Cria a coluna de status
    df_filtrado['Status'] = 'Aguardando Pagamento'
    df_filtrado.loc[df_filtrado['Data Cancelamento'].notna(), 'Status'] = 'Cancelado'
    df_filtrado.loc[df_filtrado['Data Efetivação'].notna(), 'Status'] = 'Pago'

    # Conta os status
    negociado = len(df_filtrado[df_filtrado['Status'] == 'Aguardando Pagamento'])
    pago = len(df_filtrado[df_filtrado['Status'] == 'Pago'])
    cancelado = len(df_filtrado[df_filtrado['Status'] == 'Cancelado'])
    total_negociacoes = len(df_filtrado)

    # Soma os valores da coluna 'Valor Negociado Final' por status
    soma_negociado = df_filtrado[df_filtrado['Status'] == 'Aguardando Pagamento']['Valor Negociado Final'].sum()
    soma_pago = df_filtrado[df_filtrado['Status'] == 'Pago']['Valor Negociado Final'].sum()
    soma_cancelado = df_filtrado[df_filtrado['Status'] == 'Cancelado']['Valor Negociado Final'].sum()

    # Verifica se há negociações para enviar o e-mail
    if total_negociacoes > 0:
        # Salva o relatório filtrado como Excel
        df_filtrado.to_excel(caminho_relatorio_filtrado, index=False)

        # Carrega o arquivo Excel para aplicar formatações
        wb = load_workbook(caminho_relatorio_filtrado)
        ws = wb.active

        # Adiciona formatação e tabela dinâmica (sheet 2)
        pvt_sheet = wb.create_sheet('Tabela')
        pvt_sheet.append(['Status', 'Quantidade', 'Valor Total'])
        for status in ['Aguardando Pagamento', 'Pago', 'Cancelado']:
            quantidade = len(df_filtrado[df_filtrado['Status'] == status])
            valor_total = df_filtrado[df_filtrado['Status'] == status]['Valor Negociado Final'].sum()
            pvt_sheet.append([status, quantidade, valor_total])
        pvt_sheet.append(['Total', total_negociacoes, df_filtrado['Valor Negociado Final'].sum()])

        # Aplica formatação ao cabeçalho da planilha principal
        header_font = Font(bold=True, color="FFFFFF")
        header_fill = PatternFill("solid", fgColor="4F81BD")
        for cell in ws[1]:
            cell.font = header_font
            cell.fill = header_fill
            cell.alignment = Alignment(horizontal="center")

        # Ajusta a largura das colunas e expande as células da planilha principal
        for col in ws.columns:
            max_length = 0
            column = col[0].column_letter
            for cell in col:
                try:
                    if len(str(cell.value)) > max_length:
                        max_length = len(str(cell.value))
                except Exception:
                    pass
                adjusted_width = (max_length + 2)
                ws.column_dimensions[column].width = adjusted_width

        # Adiciona borda às células da planilha principal
        thin_border = Border(left=Side(style='thin'), right=Side(style='thin'), top=Side(style='thin'), bottom=Side(style='thin'))
        for row in ws.iter_rows():
            for cell in row:
                cell.border = thin_border

        # Aplica formatação ao cabeçalho da planilha de tabela dinâmica
        for cell in pvt_sheet[1]:
            cell.font = header_font
            cell.fill = header_fill
            cell.alignment = Alignment(horizontal="center")

        # Ajusta a largura das colunas e expande as células da planilha de tabela dinâmica
        for col in pvt_sheet.columns:
            max_length = 0
            column = col[0].column_letter
            for cell in col:
                try:
                    if len(str(cell.value)) > max_length:
                        max_length = len(str(cell.value))
                except Exception:
                    pass
                adjusted_width = (max_length + 2)
                pvt_sheet.column_dimensions[column].width = adjusted_width

        # Adiciona borda às células da planilha de tabela dinâmica
        for row in pvt_sheet.iter_rows():
            for cell in row:
                cell.border = thin_border

        # Salva as alterações no arquivo Excel
        wb.save(caminho_relatorio_filtrado)

        # Configuração do e-mail
        outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
        mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
        #mail.To = 'efreis@tel.inf.br;aconstantino@tel.inf.br;enatachi@tel.inf.br;pdomingos@tel.inf.br;rogerio.oliveira@tel.inf.br;gestaohughesnet@tel.inf.br;pdomingos@tel.inf.br;acristina@tel.inf.br;paipp@hughes.com.br;mdelmondes@hughes.com.br;cnakamura@hughes.com.br'
        mail.To = 'mdelmondes@hughes.com.br;'
        mail.Subject = f'Relatório de Negociações Hora a Hora - {data_vigente}'
        mail.HTMLBody = f'''<html><body>
        <p>Prezados,</p>
        <p>Segue total de negociações de hoje:</p>
        <p>Aguardando pagamento: {negociado} - R${soma_negociado:,.2f}</p>
        <p>Pago: {pago} - R${soma_pago:,.2f}</p>
        <p>Cancelado: {cancelado} - R${soma_cancelado:,.2f}</p>
        <p>Total de Negociações: {total_negociacoes} - R${df_filtrado['Valor Negociado Final'].sum():,.2f}</p>
        <p>Atenciosamente,</p>
        <br>{outlook.Session.CurrentUser.Name}
        </body></html>'''

        # Anexa o relatório filtrado
        mail.Attachments.Add(caminho_relatorio_filtrado)
        
        # Configuração do remetente
        #mail.SentOnBehalfOfName = "cobranca.ka@hughes.com.br"

        # Envia o e-mail
        mail.Send()

        # Mostra no console que o e-mail foi enviado
        print(f'E-mail enviado com sucesso - {datetime.now()}')
    else:
        print(f'Não há negociações para enviar o e-mail - {datetime.now()}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Executa a função de enviar relatório ao iniciar o script
    enviar_relatorio()

teria alguma solução ou outra alternativa para rodar o script sem a necessidade do agendador de tarefa do windows?

Não duplique perguntas ou crie contas para contornar fechamentos, corrija o problema da pergunta original para que ela possa ser aberta, se acaso não for off-topic, siga as instruções já fornecidas. Os comentários aqui foram desativados, novos comentários devem ser feitos na pergunta original.
